# Terraform : How to attach NSG and Service Endpoints in subnet provision

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way in Azurerm to provision a subnet with an NSG attachment and also provision service endpoints as well . This is considering we have a policy to enforce NSG on subnet . So - - if subnet is a separate resource (as a separate resource nsg_id is not a parameter anymore) - it would fail the policy.

As a sub resrouce under vnet , can attach a nsg_id - but does not have parameters to provision a service endpoint or service delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deploy a service endpoint or service delegation with Terraform Language [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) or remote-exec provisioner to invoke PowerShell or CLI scripts after a resource is created.

For example, you can use [az network vnet subnet update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_vnet_subnet_update) to enable a service endpoint for the subnet.

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {

   provisioner "local-exec" {

   command = "az network vnet subnet update -g ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} -n 'subnet1' --vnet-name ${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name} --service-endpoints 'Microsoft.Sql'"
   interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
    }  
  
}
```

[image]

For more references, you could read [this blog](https://kevsoft.net/2019/04/26/multi-line-powershell-in-terraform.html)- Multi-line PowerShell in Terraform.

Comment: That would work - let me give that a spin - Thanks

Comment: Although , currently using TF cloud , which could be a bit problematic - as their workers would not have az cli.

Comment: you also could google powershell script for that.